# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1039: statement was already closed

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

Upgraded to latest Cx_Oracle release (5.1.3 to 7.1.3) and now all my code is broken. Problem appears to be occurring when attempting to pass a cursor.

```
def select_query_remy(self,sql,params=None):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        if params:
            cur.execute(sql,params)
        else:
            cur.execute(sql)
        #print cur.fetchall()
        return cur
```

I'm getting correct data in the fetchall so I know it is connecting properly and returning a valid result. So I comment it out.

In the other scripts I call it and rows should now store the cursor correct?

```
rows = con.select_query_remy(sql)
```

When I `fetchall()` from the other script I get below and get the error.

> ```
> print rows.fetchall()
> ```
>
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1039: statement was already closed

Any ideas?

full db.py

```
import cx_Oracle

class db:

list ={}    

def __init__(self):
    '''
        AMFM Python DB connectors
   '''
    db.list["disprod"] = [999,"disprod.prod.com"]
    db.list["prodqry"] = [999,"prodqry.prod.com"]
    db.list["amfmprod"] = [999,"amfmprod.prod.com"]
    db.list["esriprod"] = [999,"esriprod.prod.com"]
    db.list["amfmtest"] = [999,"amfmtest.prod.com"]
    db.list["amfmdev"] = [999,"CCTdAMFM.prod.com"]
    db.list["amfmtran"] = [999,"amfmtran.prod.com"]


def setup(self,env, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.env = env

    self.port = db.list[env][0]
    self.ip = db.list[env][1]
    if env == "prodqry":
        self.env = "prodqry.world"
    elif env == "amfmprod":
        self.env = "amfmprod.world"
    elif env == "esriprod":
        self.env = "esriprod.world"
    else:
        self.env = env
    self.connection = self.username+"/"+self.password+"@"+self.ip+":"+str(self.port)+"/"+self.env

def select_query_remy(self,sql,params=None):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection) as con:
        cur = None
        cur = con.cursor()
        if params:
            cur.execute(sql,params)
        else:
            cur.execute(sql)
        return cur
```

In another python I create a new DB and try to get the cursor back.

```
con = db()
con.setup("xxx","user","password")
rows = con.select_query_remy(sql)
print rows.fetchall()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\test\test.py", line 30, in <module>
    print rows.fetchall()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1039: statement was already closed
```

If I return fetchall() the data comes across.  When I pass the cursor itself the error occurs.

```
def select_query_remy(self,sql,params=None):
        with cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection) as con:
            cur = None
            cur = con.cursor()
            if params:
                cur.execute(sql,params)
            else:
                cur.execute(sql)
            #return cur
            return cur.fetchall()
```

Any ideas why can't I pass the cursor as it was done in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has to do with the [`with`-block](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) (also known as a *context manager*). Let me add a couple comments to the `select_query_remy` function:

```
def select_query_remy(self,sql,params=None):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection) as con:  # connects to database
        cur = None
        cur = con.cursor()
        if params:
            cur.execute(sql,params)
        else:
            cur.execute(sql)
        return cur                                # closes connection (invalidates cursor too!)
```

Since the `with`-block manages the context of the database connection, the connection will be closed after the block is exited.

To fix the error, I suggest performing `fetchall` *inside the function directly* then working with that data outside the function. (You have already kinda figured this out.)

Further Reading: [The Python Language Reference: The `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: Is this new?  It did not function this way before.

Comment: @Remy Not too sure what passed through cx_Oracle from 5.1.3 to 7.1.3 (I'm unfamiliar with the cx_Oracle module)... might be something rooted in the implementation. As a rule, limit the cursor to a specific block and don't let it run loose by returning it from a function. (See also: [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) Some database modules also allow `with`-blocks with cursors, closing them automagically on leaving the block. Make use of it if cx_Oracle implements it.

Comment: You are awesome!!!!  Exactly as you said.  Removed the with and it functions as it did in the past.

Comment: @Remy "_Removed the with_" Well... on the contrary, using `with` is good practice. It closes connections, files, etc. for us so that we don't have to forget to call `.close()` or similar (it's also exception-safe). I've suggested a couple times that refactoring your code so that the cursor is kept in one place is probably the best way to go... but, oh well. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Will make use of it as I progress, but I'm picking up where someone else left off.  Everything is configured and coded this way.  Lot of work to change, but will get it done eventually.  Thanks again.

Comment: From the [release notes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-7-0-september-2018): "When a connection is used as a context manager, the connection is now closed when the block ends. Attempts to set cx_Oracle.__future__.ctx_mgr_close are now ignored."

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error message when querying an Oracle database.  I believe it happens if there are LOB (large objects) in the database, which hasn't been the case in all the Oracle databases that I have queried.

Since I am prototyping with Jupyter, I prefer to use context manager (with) statements, and this makes manipulating the query results much more difficult if I have to add a .close() statement in a separate cell.

My workaround for this was actually to use the builtin `deepcopy` function (I tried using `.copy()` but this did not work either.  Any further manipulation/display of the data yielded the same error.

So my solution to you would be the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy
import cx_Oracle

def select_query_remy(self,sql,params=None):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        if params:
            cur.execute(sql,params)
        else:
            cur.execute(sql)
        #print cur.fetchall()
        return deepcopy(cur.fetchall())
```

I believe this should solve your issue if it was the same one that I had.

Comment: With LOBs, fetching as strings/buffers can be faster, and avoid issues with LOB locators needing to be kept open: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py

Comment: the link from @ChristopherJones is dead now (master and the file itself have been renamed), here's the updated one:
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py

Comment: It works with me.